# Is it possible to redirect with AWS ALB using AWS Lambda as a target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an ALB that has lambda as target group. Essentially, the lambda that does logic checks and returns a response:

```
{
  'statusCode': 301,
  'headers': {
     'Location': url,
  },
  'body': null,
  'isBase64Encoded': false
}
```

The response above will return a 502 bad gateway, which doesn't really help with debugging the issue. Cloudwatch says it returns the response above. The logic before the response works just fine. I would test with a status code 200, content-type application/json and a debugging message, which would return properly to the user. I know ALB has a listener for redirects, but the lambda has to go through logic to properly redirect someone first which requires things from secret manager. So the question stands, are there any other ways to redirect with alb using lambda? I tried searching through documentaries to see if there are any other limitations with lambdas as a target group. Other than the 1 mb payload/request and formatting response payload, I haven't seen anything of notice.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. We have implemented the same

1. Implement a Lambda,
2. Create a Target Group
3. Add ALB rules (if conditional)

ref: https://medium.com/trainingdock/http-redirects-with-lambda-c20cf7934060

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no. It's not lambdas role in alb to perform any redirections. If you use CloudFront, you can use lambda functions in your distribution to do redirections instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you're aiming to do is possible.
What error message do you get, when you call the lambda directly (e.g. from AWS management console)?

I could successfully test your use case with a lambda with following implementation (node run time):

```
export const handler = async (event) => ({
  statusCode: 302,
  headers: {
    Location: 'https://your-url/'
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."